# Trying to Insert Full Body of XML file into Body of Email Including Child Nodes and Elements

Tags: xml, powershell

Running into a slight issue with powershell.

I have managed to get Powershell to send an email without issue.  Initially I had the XML file included as an attachment which could be saved by the receiving individual and that worked out fine.  I was then requested to list the results of the XML file within the body of the email rather than attaching it to the email.

I have tried converting to string, and I have successfully got the XML file values listed in the string conversion, but the conversion did not retain any of the element tags or node tags listed within the document.

I tried implementing the shell script I wrote listed below:

```
###USER VARIABLES START###
#-------MODIFY AS NEEDED-------#
    #Sending account
        $from = "svmxauto@viscotec-ap.com"
    #Receiver
        $to = "dpresnell90@gmail.com"
    #Mail Subject
        $Subject = "Customer Changes MFG System" 
    #Body of Email
    
          $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\Customers_New_Changed__2023_9_15_11_29.xml ) 
        
                  $DocumentElement = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'DocumentElement']"
                  $CustomerInfo = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'CustomerInfo']"
                  $CustMfrNumber = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'CustMfrNumber']"
                  $CustMfrName = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'CustMfrName']"
                  $CustomerMfrStatus = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'CustomerMfrStatus']"
                  $CustomerMfrNameSAPNumber = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'CustomerMfrNameSAPNumber']"
                  $LastModifiedDatetime = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'LastModifiedDatetime']"
                  $LastModifiedUserID = Select-Xml -XML $xml -Xpath "//*[@key = 'LastModifiedUserID']"


                  "$($DocumentElement.node.key) = $($DocumentElement.node.value)" 
                  "$($CustomerInfo.node.key) = $($CustomerInfo.node.value)" 
                  "$($CustMfrNumber.node.key) = $($CustMfrNumber.node.value)"  
                  "$($CustMfrName.node.key) = $($CustMfrName.node.value)"
                  "$($CustMfrStatus.node.key) = $($CustMfrStatus.node.value)"
                  "$($CustMfrNameSAPNumber.node.key) = $($CustMfrNameSAPNumber.node.value)"
                  "$($LastModifiedDatetime.node.key) = $($LastModifiedDatetime.node.value)"
                  "$($LastModifiedUserID.node.key) = $($LastModifiedUserID.node.value)"        

    


    #SMTP Server
        $smtp = “mail.viscotec-ap.com"
 ###USER VARIABLES END###

###PROGRAM START###
    # Invokes the Send-MailMessage function to send notification email
        Send-MailMessage -SMTP $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $Subject -BodyAsHtml $xml
###PROGRAM END###
```

The only result that I receive from email is:

[image]

XML file should resemble the screenshot below:
[image]

I have covered all sensitive information located on the XML file.

I am sure I'm missing something as I don't script with powershell enough to fully utilize and understand its XML capabilities.

What would I need to do in order for the XML document to appear in the body of the text just as it appears in the former screenshot, with all element tags and nodes intact?

Comment: Do you have to send the body as html? Does removing `-BodyAsHtml` and just using `-Body` instead fix the issue?

Comment: @kconsiglio Thank you for your swift response!  After removing the -BodyAsHtml designation and using just -Body instead I still encounter the same result.

Comment: Having it as a string should be what gets you your expected results. So, try: `$xml = [xml]($body = Get-Content C:\temp\Customers_New_Changed__2023_9_15_11_29.xml -Raw)`, then just send `$body`: `Send-MailMessage .... -Body $body`

Comment: When sending the mail change `$xml` to `$xml.OuterXml`

Comment: Thank you @AbrahamZinala, that worked correctly!  Could you post the comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala, I was wondering if there is any way to add more characters within the body of the email message after doing this?  So far any message I try to add to the body of the message scrambles the XML file as previously posted.  If not that is perfectly okay.

Comment: Depends on what you have in mind. `$body` is a single multi-line string, and since it's a string you can concatenate other strings to it. If you wanted to add something to xml content, you'd have to modify the xml directly. If you want to add something before the string or after you can use a new line to add something like: `$body = "I'm before the xml\`n" + $body`, or `$body = $body + "\`nI'm after the xml"`